# fetching values and calculating using jQuery

Tags: jquery

i have some input fields

```
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="est_quantity" placeholder="quantity"/>
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="est_quantity" placeholder="quantity"/>
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="est_quantity" placeholder="quantity"/>

<input type="text" name="cost[]" class="est_cost" placeholder="cost"/>
<input type="text" name="cost[]" class="est_cost" placeholder="cost"/>
<input type="text" name="cost[]" class="est_cost" placeholder="cost"/>
```

i need to perform some calculations.

```
//Calculate total Quantity, this is how i do it.
$('.est_quantity').live('keyup', function(){
    var val = 0;
    $('.est_quantity').each(function() {
        if($(this).val().length && $(this).val() != '') {
            val += Number($(this).val());
            $('.est_total_quantity').html(val);
        }
    });
});
```

the above code works fine, since total quantity is the sum of all `quantity[]` however calculating the total cost is little different. since the calculation goes like this.

```
total cost = total_quantity * cost
//for each field or row.
```

while calculating the cost i want the value to be multiplied by it's corresponding quantity field.

something like

```
var cost = $('.est_quantity').val * $('.est_cost').val();
```

i tried doing it this way

```
$('.est_cost').live('keyup', function(){
    var val = 0.00;
    $('.est_cost').each(function() {
        if($(this).val().length && $(this).val() != '') {
            var cost = $(this).val() * $('.est_quantity').val();
            val += parseFloat(cost);
            $('.est_total_cost').html(val.toFixed(2));
        }
    });
});
```

the above code fetch proper calculations for only first row, for rest it fetches some weird value.

how do i go with the code for proper calculations?

P.S: initially there is one row of input fields which includes quantity and cost input fields, the rest input fields are dynamically added upon click event.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the second code sample.. you should take care that there are more than one element with `.est_quantity` class you will have to select one when you are iterating over elements with `.est_cost` class. 
something like this

```
$('.est_cost').live('keyup', function(){
    var val = 0.00;
    $('.est_cost').each(function(i) {
        if($(this).val().length && $(this).val() != '') {
            var cost = $(this).val() * $('.est_quantity').eq(i).val();
            val += parseFloat(cost);
            $('.est_total_cost').html(val.toFixed(2));
        }
    });
});
```

notice that im using `index` parameter of each function.
note:- assuming there are equal number of `.est_quantity` and `.est_cost` elements

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.est_cost, .est_quantity', function(){
    var result = 0,
        $cost = $('.est_cost'),
        $quant = $('.est_quantity');

    $.each($cost, function(i) {
        var costVal = parseFloat( $cost.eq(i).val() ),
            quantVal = parseFloat( $quant.eq(i).val() );

        if (quantVal && costVal) {
            result += costVal * qantVal;
        }
    });

    $('.est_total_cost').text( result.toFixed(2) );
});
```

Comment: thank you, this code drastically reduced my codes, better and organized.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.est_cost').each(function(index,val) {
        if($(this).val().length && $(this).val() != '') {
            var cost = $(this).val() * $('.est_quantity:eq('+ index +')').val(); //here eq(index) maintain the order
            val += parseFloat(cost);
            $('.est_total_cost').html(val.toFixed(2));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` returns an array. You're going to need to `parseFloat()` or `parseInt()` before performing calculations.

Comment: okay so i changed it to `var cost = parseFloat($(this).val()) * parseInt($('.est_quantity').val());` and now it just keeps adding the first row of inputs